# Anylogic won't start simulation (stuck on "Please wait")

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I've been developing a model for a car fleet service. I have the model ready and it works fine. The problem is when I try to put all the input trips it is supposed to do, during the course of a day, the simulation won't start, it will just get stuck on the white simulation window after I click play with the information "Please Wait". I have table in the database with all the trips (they are aggregated for simplicity, i.e. trips with same origin, destination and departure time only occupy one excel line, with the number of agents it represents, instead of one line for each agent), and while I was developing the model, I would have condition to only load the trips table until a certain departure time, so I could test the simulation quickly, this would correspond to about 100 lines of data. But now that I'm trying to load all the trips in the table (this corresponds to about 12000 lines of data), the simulation won't even start, it just gets stuck on the loading phase. I pressed play last night and it's been 10 hours and it is still stuck on the same windows with the info "Please wait".
What should I do ?
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: first thing to do is to change your database to only 10 lines of data and see if it has the same problem... if you do, then generally this happens because you have some code that never ends... for example a while loop somewhere... if you don't, then you should give information on how you are loading the database

Comment: That's the thing, if I start the simulation with the table in the database limited to, for example, the first 100 lines of data, it will run perfectly. The problem is when I try to load the entire table with 12000 lines of data, in that case it won't start. And the data table is always basically the same type, there is no loop or anything. The table is just: origin, destination, departure time, and agent count.

Comment: how are you loading this database in anylogic?

Comment: The table in the Database was loaded through an Excel file. And then in the properties of the Traveler agent (the agent that requests a car agent to do a trip), I have "Population: loaded from database", the respective table from the database, "Mode: Multiple agents per record", then I have some parameters associated to the respective columns in the table, and finally, in the Advanced properties (of the Traveler agent) I have "Optimize for: Access by index (ArrayList) and "Log to database" is ticked.

Comment: Make sure to apply indexing and "unique" columns well. These are extremely important in increasing speeds for databases. This is a general dbase topic (not AL specific) so check some resources on dbase indexing. Then index your AnyLogic dbase columns well. It can increase speeds 100x if done well

Comment: The indexing of the columns is done well. The problem is just the shear amount of agents being created. Before aggregating, the number of excel lines was almost 500,000, right now it is about 13,000, but has the agent count for those 500,000. For example, in the table with 13,000 lines, if I put the agent count to just one each, the simulation will run. But if I use the real agent count, it just won't start.

Comment: Are you getting anything written to the console? I would expect some Java memory issue.
Do a traceln for every agent that gets created to see if it gets stuck at a specific agent. 
Also review this blog posts for why you should try and use Java classes instead of agents https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/why-use-java-classes-in-anylogic

Comment: It's not writing anything on the console, because it doesn't even start the simulation, it's just stuck at the white window with "please wait". The allocated memory is 12GB, and it's only using about 5/6%. I actually got around the issue, but at a cost. I used source, delay and sink blocks, so it will only load from the database when needed, and this way, the simulation starts, because it doesn't need to generate all those agents right away, the problem is now the simulation is so slow, it is less than 1sec/sec, and I haven't even reached the critical time departures with a lot of trips

Comment: Based on low memory consumption it seems that the slowdown is mostly due to database reads. Couple of questions: 1) do you read one record at a time? 2) do you create an agent per record?

Comment: It reads the database in the beginning to generate the agents. Each trip (X origin, Y destination, Z departure time) has an agent count, so it will generate multiple agents.

Comment: In the beginning, the simulation runs fast, but as more agents (cars) are added to answer the trip needs, it gets exponentially slower. The EPS (events per second) drops just to 20/30, when in the start its about 4000/5000.

Comment: *200/300 events per second